# AlertDialog Material Design Customize with styles.xml

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-alertdialog

I have problem with customize content (message part) of AlertDialog.
As you can see in my code I was able to customize Title and Buttons for AlertDialog.

**What I need?**

Customize message in AlertDialog. 
I need to change font family to RobotoLight, textSize to 16sp and line height to 24 sp.

**What I dont want to do?**

I dont want to apply custom layout to every alertdialog i will build. I want to customize AlertDialog in styles.xml so style will apply automaticaly to every AlertDialog I will use in code ('cause it's a lot of them, one with one button, other with many, other with icons, other without icons etc).

**I don't want to use any of external libraries.**

**What I have?**

I have applied my theme in the proper way because custom style for title and buttons is working. Please see code below to refer my changes.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault.Wallpaper.NoTitleBar">
   [...]

    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>

</style>
```

My styles.xml file:

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme.DeviceDefault">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>

</style>
```

And then second part of styles.xml

```
<style name="AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/AlertDialogTitle</item>
    <!-- colorAccent : color of borderless buttons #51c1c0 -->
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/highlight</item>
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/AlertDialogButton</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/secondary_text_material_light</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/window_background_light</item>
    <item name="android:lineSpacingMultiplier">1.1</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogTitle" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/roboto_light_font</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/dialog_title_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>

<style name="AlertDialogButton" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@string/roboto_regular_font</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
</style>
```

**What I have tried?**

I have readed a tons of tutorials. In every of them authors are able and show to us how to customize title and buttons only.

I have readed a tons of stackoverflow q&a and unfortunatly I was not able to find answer.

I have tried to change textAppearance, textAppearanceMedium, textSizes, textFamily, textEverything etc and I did not achive my goal.
I have tried to create style for textAppearance, inherit from "class" like    TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium, TextAppearance.Material, TextAppearance.Material.Medium etc and nothing.

What is intresting:
http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/

I have used code snipped from above tutorial and it works (message part of AlertDialog is yellow). When I try to change theme from Holo to Material it's ends badly.

Please help! :)
Thanks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using a DialogFragment? Since it would give you absolute freedom to style, using a few lines of code.

Comment: Not sure if still relevant, but the answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36749547/562840)