# Android: message font size in alertdialog through styles

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, android-xml, android-theme, android-styles

I'm trying to change font size of message in alert dialog through styles but I can't make it work. There is a lot of answers describing how to do this but almost all of them I found do it programmatically. I want to do this once in styles, not with every new alertdialog.

What I've done so far:

In `\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\data\res\layout\alert_dialog.xml` I see the TextView that is showing the message:

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/message"
    style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="5dip" />
```

In `\AndroidSDK\platforms\android-23\data\res\values\themes.xml` I see that the value of `textAppearanceMedium` attribute is `@style/TextAppearance.Medium`.

I've created a following style of which the parent is `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium`. This style is then applied to `android:textAppearanceMedium` attribute of AlertDialog's style as follows:

```
<style name="Theme.My" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
    <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/Theme.My.AlertDialog</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.My.AlertDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="android:textAppearanceMedium">@style/MyTextAppearanceMedium</item>
</style>

<style name="MyTextAppearanceMedium" parent="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Medium">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
</style>
```

...but the font size won't change. What's wrong?

I'm using AppCompat support lib, min SDK 16, target SDK 23.

Thank you.

Answer (score 9):

If we go through the android sources we will find that `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert` theme inherits alertDialogStyle:

```
<item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light</item>
```

Going through the `AlertDialog.AppCompat.Light` style we will find that it uses default layout:

```
<item name="android:layout">@layout/abc_alert_dialog_material</item>
```

Further investigating sources, particularly layout `@layout/abc_alert_dialog_material`, we will see that `TextView` with id `android:id="@android:id/message"` (this is message `TextView`) uses style `TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead`

```
<TextView
    android:id="@android:id/message"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead"
    ... />
```

Overriding those style in app's `values/styles.xml` file will change appearance of message in alert dialog:

```
<style name="TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" parent="Base.TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead">
    <item name="android:textSize">24sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ff0000</item> <!-- we can change other parameters, e.g. textColor -->
</style>
```

Comment: Your solution is not complete. So it's not working. How to override textView style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead" ?

Comment: It works as expected. style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead is a custom style, override it like other styles by creating a new style and specifying it's parent="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhea">.

Comment: Perfect! Working as a charm. Thank yo!!!

Answer (score 6):

AlertDialog was using the theme attribute `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"` for dialog content until Material Theme.

If you look at the source code of `AlertDialog` it uses an `AlertController`to manage the `AlertDialog`. In `AlertDialog` constructor we have this :

```
 TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(null,
             com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog,
             com.android.internal.R.attr.alertDialogStyle, 0);

     mAlertDialogLayout = a.getResourceId(com.android.internal.R.styleable.AlertDialog_layout,
             com.android.internal.R.layout.alert_dialog);
```

We can see that the layout for the `AlertDialog`comes from an attribute called "**layout**" declared in `declare-styleable name=AlertDialog` and defined at theme level in the attribute `alertDialogStyle`.

Know, looking at `alertDialogStyle` in Material theme we got this
`<item name="alertDialogStyle">@style/AlertDialog.Material</item>`

and at **Alert.Dialog.Material** we got `<item name="layout">@layout/alert_dialog_material</item>`

It's using **alert_dialog_material** and not **alert_dialog**.

In **alert_dialog_material** we have the same `TextView`

```
<TextView android:id="@+id/message"
                      style="@style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead"
                      android:layout_width="match_parent"
                      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                      android:paddingStart="@dimen/alert_dialog_padding_material"
                      android:paddingTop="@dimen/alert_dialog_padding_top_material"
                      android:paddingEnd="@dimen/alert_dialog_padding_material" />
```

but the style points to a local theme instead of `?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium` and that's why you can't style the message like before.

**SOLUTION 1:**

We can only do this programmatically. Get the `TextView`using the window from the Dialog and set the appearance you want:

```
android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog d = builder.show();
TextView tv = (TextView)d.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
```

**SOLUTION 2:**

To make it more flexible we can define an attribute in `attrs.xml`

```
<resources>
    <attr name="dialogMessageStyle" format="reference"/>
</resources>
```

Define the attribute in your theme:

```
<style name="MyStyle" ...>
    <item name="dialogMessageStyle">@style/AlertDialogMessageAppearance</item>
</style>
```

And set it in code using:

```
 TextView tv = (TextView)d.getWindow().findViewById(android.R.id.message);
            TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(new int[]{R.attr.dialogMessageStyle});
            tv.setTextAppearance(DialogActivity.this,a.getResourceId(0,0));
```