# How to change the style of the message of the dialog?

Tags: android

my codes:

```
backDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext(), R.style.dialogAlertTheme)
            .setTitle(R.string.hint)
            .setMessage(R.string.clear_all_cache)
            .setPositiveButton(R.string.confirm, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    clearCache();
                }
            }).setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, null).create();
backDialog.show();
```

dialogAlertTheme:

```
<style name="dialogAlertTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.MinWidth">
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/customButtonBarPositiveButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/customButtonBarNegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/customButtonBarWindowTitleStyle</item>
</style>
```

I can change the style of the title by changing the "android:windowTitleStyle".

I can change the sytle of the buttons by changing the "buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle" and the "buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle".

But How can I change the style of message?
I tried a lot such as "android:textAppearance", "android:dialogPreferenceStyle", and so on, not work.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: bug fixed. refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179537/android-message-font-size-in-alertdialog-through-styles

Answer (score 0):

You can change the colors as you wish by changing the standard colors used throughout AppCompat themes and applying it to the dialog like you did (providing the theme in constructor)

```
<style name="MainTheme.Dialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I tried to do it as u said, but it doesn't work.As I know, these field can only change the color of the statusbar or actionbar.Thank u anyway.^_^

Comment: @2013 It depends where you apply it obviously. If you apply it to the dialog then it will apply to dialog only. For instance, changing `colorAccent` will change dialog button's color

Comment: thanks a lot. I've changed the color of the message by changing the "android:textColorPrimary". refer to this post, http://blog.supenta.com/2014/07/02/how-to-style-alertdialogs-like-a-pro/ , I  can't change the textsize of the message by defining the "android:textAppearanceMedium" however...

Comment: same problem refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179537/android-message-font-size-in-alertdialog-through-styles

Answer (score 0):

You can try **textAppearanceMedium**.

I refer to the source code, and there are following segment in **alert_dialog.xml**

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="2dip"
        android:paddingBottom="12dip"
        android:paddingStart="14dip"
        android:paddingEnd="10dip"
        android:overScrollMode="ifContentScrolls">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/message"
            style="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="5dip" />
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Then you can find the TextView which id is message uses the style of 
**?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium**

I wish this can work for you.

Comment: I tried this before, also refered to the source code as u, but neither the "android:textAppearanceMedium" nor the "android:textAppearance" work. I'd like to change the mMessageView, field of AlertController, which corresponding the "@+id/message" as u see. Thank u anyway.^_^

Comment: Do you know why this way doesn't work and which theme is used for the Dialog?

Comment: Besides,I see that it work well for Android4.4, but not for Android5.0

Comment: parent Theme is @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.MinWidth

Comment: same problem refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35179537/android-message-font-size-in-alertdialog-through-styles